# How best to add other apps/modules to a GAS project

Tags: google-apps-script

I currently have an app that creates spreadsheets for measuring potholes, and I plan on building other apps (or should I call these modules?), including one for logging the location of potholes, one for viewing the potholes on a map, and one that estimates the surface area of a pothole.

The transition diagram for all this looks something like:

[image: transition diagram]

The dotted lines in the diagram represent state transition due to data sent.

Instinct tells me to get to work developing these other apps/modules, as separate apps, and then connect them somehow. There's, however, some problems with this approach:

- user would have to authorize every app they visit (that sucks!)
- possible permissions problems (who should each app run as and why?)

There's another approach that I know of: bring it all into the app I have up, separating the module pages. However, that approach has some setbacks:

- the code base becomes mess because no folders to separate the modules
- the same user has access to it all (one click and they authorize it all), but should not necessarily have access to it all. For example, a member of the general public using the app to report a pothole should probably have access to the "Add Pothole" feature, but not to the spreadsheet module that I just made. *This may become non-issue as it may literally be finding out what screen all users have access to, putting everything on there, and deleting the stuff that should not be accessible to unauthorized users.*

How should I hope to handle this?

Comment: If you have a gsuite business account you can try out [AppMaker](https://developers.google.com/appmaker/overview)

Comment: @RobinGertenbach I don't have a GSuite business account. That costs money I don't have right now. 

With AppMaker, would I make all the screens from App Selection (all the modules) into one app?

Comment: Yes, you also would not need to worry about the code generating the screens as it's a drag and drop interface. But yes, it does cost money